Is there a way to select a row of a table with a specific column value that also displays its row number from the in original table in phpmyadmin?
I am trying to make a full-stack CRUD web app using mysql through phpmyadmin, which will be sent to an express front end (this is my first time ever working with SQL and PHP so pardon my mistakes or my lack of knowledge) For example, my table in PHP:
ID  Name  Time      Date  

1   COR   01:40:37  01/24/24

2   BING  01:39:38  01/23/24


whose values have been inserted with user input. Is the following possible?
First by getting the row number and sorting by 'time':
ID  Name   Time      Date       Rn

2   BING   01:39:38  01/23/24   1

1   COR    01:40:37  01/24/24   2

However I only want the following output when 'BING' is searched:
ID  Name   Time      Date      Rn

2   BING   01:39:38  01/23/24  1

My search function is:
async searchByName(name) {
        try{
            const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const query = "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) rn FROM medley_relay; SELECT * FROM medley_relay WHERE name = ?;";
// try separating the two queries
                connection.query(query, [name], (err, results) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
                    resolve(results);
                })
            });
            console.log(response)
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

This is called by:
app.get('/search/:name', (request, response) => {
    const {name} = request.params;
    const db = dbService.getDbServiceInstance();

    const result = db.searchByName(name);

    

    result
    .then(data => response.json({data : data}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
    console.log(result);
})

and activated through the front end with an HTML input element:
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('#search-btn');

searchBtn.onclick = function() {
    const searchValue = document.querySelector('#search-input').value;

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/search/' + searchValue)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => loadHTMLTable(data['data']));
}

My loadHTMLTable function is:
function loadHTMLTable(data) {
    const table = document.querySelector('table tbody');

    console.log(data);

    if (data.length === 0) {
        table.innerHTML = "<tr><td class='no-data'>No Data</td><td class = 'no-data'colspan='5'>No Data</td></tr>";
        return;
    }

    let tableHtml = "";

    data.forEach(function ({id, name, time, date, rn}) {
    
        tableHtml += "<tr>";
        tableHtml += `<td>${rn}</td>`;
        tableHtml += `<td>${name}</td>`;
        tableHtml += `<td>${time}</td>`;
        tableHtml += `<td>${new Date(date).toLocaleDateString()}</td>`;
        tableHtml += `<td><button class="delete-row-btn" data-id=${id}>Delete</td>`;
        tableHtml += `<td><button class="edit-row-btn" data-id=${id}>Edit</td>`;
        tableHtml += "</tr>";
        
    });

    table.innerHTML = tableHtml;

}

If I only use the query:
const query = "SELECT * FROM medley_relay WHERE name = ?;"; and name is passed through, I get an undefined value for rn because it hasn't been defined through the ROW_NUMBER function. However when I do add the ROW_NUMBER FUNCTION I get:
[
  [
    RowDataPacket {
      id: 15,
      name: 'Corning',
      time: '01:40:15',
      date: 2024-04-10T04:00:00.000Z,
      rn: 1
    },
    RowDataPacket {
      id: 16,
      name: 'Binghamton',
      time: '01:52:42',
      date: 2024-04-02T04:00:00.000Z,
      rn: 2
    }
  ],
  [
    RowDataPacket {
      id: 16,
      name: 'Binghamton',
      time: '01:52:42',
      date: 2024-04-02T04:00:00.000Z
    }
  ]
]

with undefined values across my entire table. Is there a way to do this without getting a nested array and only the array at index [0][1]? Right now my query to load the data from the array without restricting it to any name looks like:
app.get('/getAll', (request, response) => {
    const db = dbService.getDbServiceInstance();

    const result = db.getAllData();

    result
    .then(data => response.json({data : data}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
})

and
async getAllData() {
        try{
            const response = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                const query = "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) rn FROM medley_relay ORDER BY rn;" 
                "SELECT * FROM medley_relay;";
                connection.query(query, (err,results) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
                    resolve(results);
                })
            });
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

In this case it does work to have both of these queries like this and my table functions correctly. Why is it that when I change "SELECT * FROM medley_relay;" to "SELECT * FROM medley_relay WHERE name = ?;" it stops working? I've tried to use a dedicated column to contain the value of row numbers that would constantly refresh to match updates and deletions, but it doesn't seem like that is possible.

this code doesn't seem to be using any PHP

the logic you describe may like folllow:
if name is not empty 
    const query = "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) rn FROM medley_relay where name = ?; "; 
else 
    const query = "SELECT * FROM medley_relay WHERE name = ? ORDER by time;"; 


Name is never empty, its just that my query isn't returning what I want it to be. The name input works perfectly fine, its the row number that isn't being kept.

oh~ get it! Karl Hill puts the right solution
